# Should identity column be added table that uses date and a foreign key?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database, t-sql, database-design

I'm making a small asp.net mvc application that allows me to set up dish schedules for me and the people in my house. I have a table called DishDates that keeps track of who has a dish day on which date. It currently contains 3 columns (DishDateId, PersonId, and Date). DishDateId is the PK, PersonId is a FK to the Person table and Date is the date of the day the dishes are on.

We only have one person on dishes on any given day. The PersonId is tied to a Date. My app can auto generate a dish calendar for the month. Now, you can also go in and regenerate a new dish list for a month that has already had one created, the application goes and deletes the existing records for that month and then creates them. Every time I do this, the DishDateId field's values increase because it is an identity column.

I know that this won't really be a problem because I can have over 2 billion rows still which will suffice for way longer than the lifetime of this app. But, would this be a case where it would be smarter to not use the identity column and just have the PersonId and Date field and make Date the PK? I feel like the Identity column is just kind of in the way or something, or unnecessary.

[image: ScreenShot of DishDates Data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When recreating the PersonId and Dates values, you could simply create them in a temp table and use the MERGE function based on matching the dates (as they are the constant value and the PersonId the variable value in any given row).

Yes, you don't need the identity column of DateDishId per se, but if using the process above, then the count of rows will be not increased for every iteration of the same Months' data.

I'll let you calculate how long it will take you to fill up the identity column with the dates though, but given that the Identity is likely an INT, then you, me, your roommates, or the world as we know it, is unlikely to be around, so it's nothing to sweat about!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set date as PK as per your requirement, as it assign new date every day to next person and also it is identity column as you said.

**Confusion :** How you have assign identity to date column?

Comment: Date column is not an identity column. The DishDateId column is the identity column. The app that this database is connected to generates the dish dates and sends it to this table. Again, given the requirements, the dishdates will be unique since there is only one person per day on dishes.